# Adding --no-check-certificate to yum repositories

Tags: centos, ssl, yum

I have added `virtio-win.repo` according to this [guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers#Yum.7CDnf_Repo). The content of `/etc/yum.repo.d/virtio-win.repo` is now

```
[virtio-win-stable]
name=virtio-win builds roughly matching what was shipped in latest RHEL
baseurl=http://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/stable
enabled=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=0

[virtio-win-latest]
[virtio-win-source]
```

The last two `[]` have similar options as the first (which are not my problem). Now, when I run `yum makecache`, I get this error

```
http://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection
```

I tried running `wget http://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/stable/repodata/repomd.xml` manually, but it recommends me to add `--no-check-certificate` to `wget` which will solve the problem.

I want to know how can I add that option in the `/etc/yum.repo.d/virtio-win.repo`?

Answer (score 46):

For one repo you can add the following in the repo configuration:

```
sslverify=0
```

For all repos, you can add the following to "/etc/yum.conf":

```
sslverify=false
```

Comment: No. it has no effect

Comment: Try also changing back to https for the URL.  Be aware that by changing sslverify to off you are foregoing protection against MITM attacks.

Comment: Do you guys know if this applies to scenarios where I'm trying to disable SSL for URLs:

I'm trying to run `yum install <URL>`, but disabling sslverify in the `yum.conf`, doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Worked great for me on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511.

Answer (score 9):

On CentOS 7.5, running this worked:

```
yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<REPONAME>.sslverify=false
```

Answer (score 3):

The ssl check is there for a reason. It is really dangerous to disable ssl certificate check. I prefer this approach:
One of my customer's environment is not set u properly, where the SSL certificate of the proxy server signs every ssl cert of every site. To verify that this is the problem, I run

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

It fails, so, get the certificate with one command using openssl-client

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.google.com -connect www.google.com:443 > cacert.pem
```

The big file has the server cert in the middle, copy it, and save it to new file, we will call it mycert.pem. The cert starts with Begin Certificate, and ends with End of Certificate

Let's test it to verify

```
curl https://www.google.com --cacert mycert.pem
```

It it works, then the problem is resolved. All what we need to do is to add it to the repository where curl uses as trusted repository.
To get the location of the certificates, do the following

```
strace curl https://www.google.com |& grep open
```

Lots of output, but right near the end I see:
open("/etc/ssl/certs/578d5c04.0", O_RDONLY) = 4

Which is where my certificates are stored. Then simply append the file got earlier.

```
echo "#Added by me , the client\'s certificate" >> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
cat mycert.pem >> /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Then test again with curl, now without the certificate as an option

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

It should get the certificate.

Comment: This helps for curl, but doesn't seem to fix issues for yum/dnf

Answer (score 1):

On Centos 6, need to update nss

## yum update nss

The error "... [Errno 14] problem making ssl connection" no longer occurs

Comment: Why? I think nss has nothing to do to that. It is about resolving names (mostly, hostnames).

Comment: URL         : http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/
Summary     : Network Security Services
Description :
Network Security Services (NSS) is a set of libraries designed to
support cross-platform development of security-enabled client and
server applications. Applications built with NSS can support SSL v2
and v3, TLS, PKCS #5, PKCS #7, PKCS #11, PKCS #12, S/MIME, X.509
v3 certificates, and other security standards.